# migrate from oracle db to mysql using Liquibas

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to migrate from oracle db to mysql or postgres using Liquibas. I have generated the sql file using Liquibase but,  the syntax is not right there is a lot of issue with the generated sql. If anyone has any solution please do let me know thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to use the [generateChangeLog function](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html) to create an XML changeSet description of your oracle database. Go through the generated changelog to make sure everything expected is there, and make any changes to the file as needed such as data type changes.

Once the changelog is correct, you can run the XML changelog directly against your mysql or postgresql database or use updateSQL to generate the SQL liquibase would use. Liquibase will create the correct database-specific SQL when it runs a changelog against a given database.